# To print out jquery version, Why we use $() and what does it mean?

Tags: jquery

I saw the following code which can print out the jquery version

```
$().jquery
```

I am wondering what does $() mean here?

Comment: creates an empty jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

It just creates an empty jQuery object so you can access its `jquery` property. This is in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> **Returning an Empty Set**
>
> As of jQuery 1.4, calling the `jQuery()` method with no arguments returns an empty jQuery set (with a `.length` property of 0). In previous versions of jQuery, this would return a set containing the document node.

---

Side note: If you just want the version, you don't have to do that, you can use `$.fn.jquery` and avoid creating the object (not that doing so is expensive).

Comment: @AdamLee: jQuery uses JavaScript's prototypical inheritance, which means that all jQuery objects have a prototype object "behind" them that supplies them with their methods and most of their properties. jQuery puts the `fn` property on the `jQuery` (`$`) function and points it at the prototype it uses, so `$.fn` refers to the prototype, which has the `jquery` property on it. More in, again, [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/).

Comment: I am not sure I understand why $.fn refers to the prototype?

Comment: @AdamLee: Because they did that explicitly. When you call the `jQuery` function, it just turns around does `return new jQuery.fn.init(/*...*/);` to build the object it returns. When initializing the library, they build up the methods and such that should be inherited by jQuery instances on `jQuery.fn` and then after creating the `init` function, they do `init.prototype = jQuery.fn;`. So objects created via `new jQuery.fn.init(...)` get `jQuery.fn` as their prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery syntax is tailor made for selecting HTML elements and perform some action on the element(s).

Basic syntax is: `$(selector).action()`

A dollar sign to define  A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements A jQuery action() can be performed on the element(s)